# How to find duplicate field in rows using SQL

Tags: mysql

I want to display two records from column "name" and column "birth" so that each gets the number of duplicates using `COUNT ()`

[image]

I'm using query

```
SELECT 
    nama,  COUNT(nama),
    lahir,  COUNT(lahir)
FROM tb_test
GROUP BY nama , lahir
HAVING  COUNT(nama) > 1 AND COUNT(lahir) > 1;
```

But the result is always null

[image]

Comment: Please don't use images for code, data or errors - use formatted text. This looks like you are using MySQL - which is completely different to SQL Server, so please ensure your tags a consistent with your question.

Comment: Sorry about question, The sql query runs and there are no errors but the result is always empty

Comment: If you provide your sample data as DDL+DML you make it much easier for people to assist. And provide your desired results (as tabular text *not* image).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're looking for separate columns with the count adjacent.  Try this:

```
select 
    t.nama, (select count(1) from tb_test cn where cn.nama = t.nama) as cnt_nama, 
    t.lahir, (select count(1) from tb_test cn where cn.lahir = t.lahir) as cnt_lahir
from tb_test t
;
```

Obviously anything with a two or greater has duplicates.  You could put this all in a subquery depending on your requirement.  That would be something like this:

```
select s.* 
from ( 
    select 
        t.nama, (select count(1) from tb_test cn where cn.nama = t.nama) as cnt_nama, 
        t.lahir, (select count(1) from tb_test cn where cn.lahir = t.lahir) as cnt_lahir
    from tb_test t
) s 
where s.cnt_nama > 1 or s.cnt_lahir > 1
;
```

Comment: almost a little more to what I want, this query returns column "lahir" with count 1 it should only show if column "lahir" count is more than 1. just show duplicate data from column "nama" and "lahir". If the coloumn "lahir" or "name" i is not a duplicate, it is not necessary to display or provide information

Comment: @Robby even the subquery version does not meet the requirement?  That is, the second query show select s.* from (.....

Answer (score 0):

You probably want `HAVING COUNT(id) > 1`. But even so there are no rows in that sample data with the same `nama` and `lahir` values.

You might also want this:

```
SELECT 'nama' as `Field`, nama as `Value`, count(id) as `Count`
FROM tb_test
GROUP BY nama
HAVING  COUNT(id) > 1

UNION

SELECT 'lahir' as `Field`, lahir as `Value`, count(id) as `Count`
FROM tb_test
GROUP BY lahir
HAVING  COUNT(id) > 1
```

Comment: This command works but I want to display it side by side

Comment: example nama in COUNT(nama) lahir in COUNT(lahir)

Comment: How will you display them side by side if there are different numbers of results for each part of the union? Given the duplicates likely represent different records, what is the relationship between a name and birthdate that would make a particular birthdate show alongside a particular name? From and SQL and relational algebra standpoint, it makes **absolutely no sense** to show the data that way. What you really have is two separate queries... hence the `UNION`.